# Accessing JSON object within Object using React/Axios

Tags: json, reactjs, api, object, axios

I’m working with an API that shows data for cryptocurrencies called CryptoCompare. I’m a React noob but I’ve managed to use Axios to do the AJAX request. However I’m having trouble accessing the JSON elements I want.

Here’s what the JSON looks like: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist

Here is my request:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";
var NumberFormat = require('react-number-format');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coinList: []
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist`)
    .then(res => {
      const coins = res.data;
      //console.log(coins);
      this.setState({ coinList: coins});
    });
  }



// Object.keys is used to map through the data. Can't map through the data without this because the data is not an array. Map can only be used on arrays.
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.coinList.Data);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(this.state.coinList).map((key) => (
          <div className="container">
            <span className="left">{key}</span>
            <span className="right"><NumberFormat value={this.state.coinList[key].CoinName} displayType={'text'} decimalPrecision={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am able to output some JSON using console.log(this.state.coinList.Data);. It outputs the JSON object, but I am unable to console.log properties of the object itself.

How would I, for example, output the CoinName property of the first element 42?

console.log(this.state.coinList.Data.CoinName) doesn’t work

nor does console.log(this.state.coinList.Data[0].CoinName) etc…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over `this.state.coinList` while you want to iterate over `this.state.coinList.Data`.

Try this:

```
  render() {
    const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
    if (data == null) return null;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
          <div className="container">
            <span className="left">{key}</span>
            <span className="right"><NumberFormat value={data[key].CoinName} displayType={'text'} decimalPrecision={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rvy94myl1

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled with that same problem as yours. **You cannot access an object inside a data because it is empty when the render happens**.
 What I did was I made a **conditional render** where if the data is empty, it will just show a loading screen or something like that. And when the data loads , it will access the object inside that data. I can now access the object inside because I waited for the data to load inside render.

I hope this answer can help future react users

```
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.coinList.length>0? <h1>{this.state.coinList[0].coinName}</h1>: "Loading"}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Added: To **console.log** the data , you can create a **new component** inside the conditional render. Inside that component, you can access all the data you want because it is rendered after the data is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You're might have to parse the JSON. Might be good to do that before you save it.

```
  const coins = JSON.parse(res.data)
```